# Execute jdbc applet in browser

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<applet code="A0" width=250 height=200>
</applet>
*/

public class A0 extends Applet implements ActionListener,ItemListener
{
String msg="";

Button view,delete,create,edit,reapp,exit;
TextField M_head;
int x,i,ans=0,flag;

public void init()
{
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,50,3));

view = new Button("view");
delete = new Button("delete");
create = new Button("create");
edit = new Button("edit");
reapp = new Button("reapp");
exit= new Button("exit");
M_head = new TextField(15);

add(view);
add(delete);
add(create);
System.out.println("vikram");
add(edit);
add(reapp);
add(exit);
System.out.println("phaneendra");
add(M_head);

view.addActionListener(this);
delete.addActionListener(this);
create.addActionListener(this);
edit.addActionListener(this);
reapp.addActionListener(this);
exit.addActionListener(this);
M_head.addActionListener(this);




}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

String str=ae.getActionCommand();

if(str.equals("view"))
{msg ="1";}
if(str.equals("delete"))
{msg ="2";}
if(str.equals("create"))
{msg ="3";}
if(str.equals("edit"))
{msg ="4";}
if(str.equals("reapp"))
{msg ="5";}
if(str.equals("exit"))
{msg ="6";}

if(msg=="3")
{

try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
//String filename = "E:/vikram/conn/new/db/north.mdb";
String filename = "./db/north.mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
//String url ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\cheminDeMaBaseEtNomdeLaBdd";
database+=filename.trim();
String head = M_head.getText();
String head1 = head.trim();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database,"","");
Statement doo = con.createStatement();
//String vi ="create table head1 (Reapporder integer, Amount integer)";
String vi="insert into head1 values(1,2);";

boolean i=false;
i=doo.execute(vi);

if(i)
M_head.setText("Failed to insert");

else
M_head.setText("record inserted");

}


catch(Exception err)
{
System.out.println("Error :"+err);
}


}




}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
{
repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawString(msg,70,200); //No use

g.drawString("ANSWER=",6,200); // No use

}
}
```

### This is A0.txt

```
grant {
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission
"accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc";
permission java.util.PropertyPermission
"file.encoding", "read";
};
```

### A0.html file

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<applet code=A0     width=250 height=200></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is executed in `Appletviewer` command, but not in any browser

Comment: Using JDBC in an applet isn't the best of idea. Attempting to use the JDBC-ODBC is hopeless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by others, you really don't want to do this.

Just create a webservice in the server side (which can be a plain vanilla servlet) and make use of [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) in the applet.

Basic Servlet example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action"); // Or request.getPathInfo() whatever you want.
    String result = someDAO.doAction(action);
    response.getWriter().write(result);
}
```

Basic Applet example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/databaseservlet?action=someaction");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream result = connection.getInputStream(); // Important. This actually fires the request!
```

Be careful with [SQL injections](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) however. Do in no way pass raw SQL queries as request parameters or pathinfo and use [`PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) all the time in the DAO code.

As response data format you can use a plain vanilla String (as given in example) or a [XML string](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) or a [JSON string](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or maybe even a fullworthy Java object with a little help of [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Comment: in type 1 driver how can i upload my website into ftp area.

and is  it possible without tomcat or any other server is it possibel to run servlets?


thats way am using applets.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do JDBC on an Applet for security reasons.

You must write an Enterprise Application (in Java, .NET, Python, PHP) and deploy it to an application server. In that application you can publish some WebServices so your Applet can finally access your database.

Something like this:

**APPLET <-> APPLICATION SERVER (HTTP communication) <-> BACKEND (database)**

[Here](http://www.wutka.com/hackingjava/ch3.htm) is a Web Site explaining some security related Applet stuff.

Comment: grant {permission java.lang.RuntimePermission"accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc";permission java.util.PropertyPermission"file.encoding", "read";};

This file kept in .jar file and then add in applet tag archeve attribute ?????