# database values are not showing in applet when embedding on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, applet

My applet is running well and showing all the data from the database, which i required. But, the problem is when i embed the created jar file on jsp. it didn't show the data from the database.

```
<applet code="myform.Form" archive="applet.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
```

applet is running on the jsp page, but in the combo box items (from the database) are not available to select.
jar file is located in the same directory, where jsp page is located.
Thanks in advance.

this is my applet code

```
package myform;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Form extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    /** Initializes the applet Form */
    public void init() {
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String connstr="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE";
            String uname="epolicia";
            String pass="admin";
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            Connection connect =DriverManager.getConnection(connstr,uname,pass);
            // System.out.println("Oracle driver is loaded");
            Statement state=connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ZONE");

            while (rs.next()) {
                zoneList.addItem(rs.getString(2)+" ("+rs.getString(1)+")");
                //System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //list.addItem(ex);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        zoneList = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        addDistrict = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cancelDistrict = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        jLabel1.setText("District ID :");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        jLabel2.setText("District Name :");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        jLabel3.setText("Zone :");

        addDistrict.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        addDistrict.setText("Add");


        addDistrict.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jLabel5.setText("index: " + zoneList.getSelectedItem());//addDistrictActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cancelDistrict.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12));
        cancelDistrict.setText("Cancel");
        cancelDistrict.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cancelDistrictActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24));
        jLabel4.setText("Add New District");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 157, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2)
                            .addComponent(zoneList, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                        .addComponent(addDistrict)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(cancelDistrict))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(163, 163, 163)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(zoneList, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(addDistrict)
                    .addComponent(cancelDistrict))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLabel5.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("lbl");
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void addDistrictActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    private void cancelDistrictActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addDistrict;
    private javax.swing.JButton cancelDistrict;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox zoneList;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: You must provide more information.

Comment: On another note, you probably don't want your applet to connect to your database (as anybody having the applet can access to the password in it). I don't know what's your architecture, but better safe than sorry :)

Comment: like what... tell me .. i'll provide all the information.

Comment: how should i get the data from the database in my applet, i mean, where i'm making mistake.please..

Comment: @sql_query: some code... we can only guess what's going wrong. Btw: how do you know that your applet works fine (first sentence)?

Comment: because, applet is running and showing the data in combo box, when run it separately.

Comment: i've uploaded the code of applet.

Comment: Do you see some exception in the java console?

Comment: @Pablo i'm running this code on NetBeans, where i didn't get any exception. Whereas, i've already mentioned that, i'm getting correct output in my applet.

Comment: @sql_query applets are executed on the client, not on the server. You won't see any exception in an applet embedded in a page in the server. You'll see them in the java console of the client.

Comment: so... what should i do.?

Comment: @sql_query check the java console on the client...

Comment: what is the difference. it's working fine on the NetBeans. even it's working on jsp also. The only difference is i'm not getting any values from the database in applet (when i embedding it on jsp).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7704/discussion-between-sql-query-and-pablo)

Comment: @sql_query I suspect that the problem is that you don't have access to the database driver in the client, so you can't access the database. Or perhaps the client machine and the sever machine are not the same, so the database ip ("localhost") doesn't work in the client. Seriously, check the java console, there is probably an exception there. If you don't know how to check it, it's easy to find using google. I'll pass on the chat. I'm not a native english speaker, so I write slowly, and a chat is uncomfortable if I have to check words in a dictionary.

Comment: I've deleted my answer b/c adding JDBC JAR was against browser security policy... I give up

Comment: so, what should i do.. please help me... :(

Comment: are you accessing applet in your browser as `http://localhost` or as a file?

Answer (score 2):

Doing your JDBC access on the server side and providing a web service for the applet is the better approach: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901404/execute-jdbc-applet-in-browser) covers the topic pretty well.

Posting as an answer because the comments are getting pretty crowded, but this should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are not deploying Oracle JDBC drivers along with your JAR?

To include Oracle driver dependency you will need to put `ojdbc6.jar` (or another version) next to the `applet.jar` on the server (or in the local folder if you're running locally).

Then you need to make your browser Java classpath aware of it. You can do that by either adding it to the `archive` attribute after comma:

`<applet code="myform.Form" archive="applet.jar,ojdbc6.jar" width="600" height="480"/>`

or by adding it to `applet.jar`'s Manifest file (if there are more than one JARs separate them by space): `Class-Path: ojdbc6.jar`

**EDIT**:
Oracle has specifically mentioned in their documentation that it was possible to use their JDBC driver from Applets. However they mention security issues etc.

The exception given by the `ojdbc14.jar` could mean that you're trying to access a different DB server - not the one applet is coming from. If you're running applet from local filesystem that's pretty logical.

To avoid this error you will need to sign your applet as described in [section 24.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/applet.htm#i1025242) of their doc.

Comment: have you looked at browser java console?

Comment: in java console .. i'm getting this message
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.management.MBeanServerPermission createMBeanServer)

Comment: Could you try replacing `ojdbc6.jar` with `classes14.jar` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc101040-094982.html)?

Comment: i didn't find classes14.jar. i only found classes12.jar and ojdbc14.jar

Comment: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:316)

Comment: address given in the section 24.2.2 topic http://java.sun.com/security/signExample/index.html is not found. Now, what to do.?