# Connection to a remote database through an Applet

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

I made a applet that includes JDBC sql connector.
On my pc I can connect to the database on my server, so that works.
But when I put the applet in my browser it doesn't work.
When I load JDBC with it, it gives me an error.
And when I don't load the archive it does loads, but it doesn't connect.

Now my qeustion is.
How to connect ?
and is it possible some how to hide my database account info.
Because if I use mywebsite/java/UCP.class I can open it and I can read the password of my database account out of it...

So maybe somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons it would be better to create a web endpoint that mediates between your applet and your database.

More information here:

[Execute jdbc applet in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901404/execute-jdbc-applet-in-browser)

and here:

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/java.101/b10979/applet.htm

Comment: Okay so I got this: 

RL url = new URL("http://example.com/databaseservlet?action=someaction");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream result = connection.getInputStream(); // Important. This actually fires the request!

Now I'm wondering how can I ever run a query or connect to the database with this ?...

And how can I format a post on this website? why are they not just using html format or something that does works.

Comment: You need to create a servlet on the server side that actually does  the database connection. Then you can read the content from the InputStream, I would suggest using some sort of encoding, maybe JSON, you can populate your applet data from there.

Comment: Why nobody can just give me a simple example of getting the connection information from a servet or whatever it is.
I don't know what a servlet it, and when I search for it, I only get 10000 lines with code that isn't understandable... 
Why should it be so hard to connect an applet to a sql database...
Why they even made applets if this is almost unpossible to do something usefuls with it...

Comment: So you are telling me that every single java code on the web is using this methode to get information from a database... I don't believe that.

Comment: Most people don't write Applets, because they are limited because of security constraints, and require the user to have Java installed.